# Setting Multi Statement as 0 for Snowflake in Talend tdbconnection

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I am trying to set MULTI_STATEMENT_COUNT=0 in Talend when making tdbconnection.

I had to add a seperate tSnowflakeRow right now to set this parameter using ALTER SESSION.

Is there any way to do that during making connection when using tDBConnection?

Comment: You can do at the "account" level but session level is better in terms of security due to sql injections. The other thing is instead of setting MULTI_STATEMENT_COUNT=0, which is unlimited number of SQL's , it is better to call the setParameter  and pass the number of SQL's that you will be calling.

Answer (score 1):

A session parameter can be set at user level ([CREATE USER](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-user.html)).
So this parameter will be set as soon as you initiate your connection.

But as indicated by @hkandpal and noticed in [Snowflake documentation](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/jdbc-using.html#multi-statement-support) you should be cautious with **MULTI_STATEMENT_COUNT** parameter as it opens up the possibility for SQL injection.